# Bayesian meta-analysis of multiple ranked lists?

Tags: bayesian, ranking, probabilistic-programming

Let's say I go around and ask a bunch of my friends to rank 30 movies. Each one returns me a list. Now the obvious treatment is to average the rankings, but I'm wondering if anyone has seen a more rigorous Bayesian treatment. For example, we can assume there is some latent "goodness" parameter $\theta$ drawn from a normal distribution and some noise associated with each person's list. Going further we can say that each person $i$ draws a $\theta_i$ from the distribution. The complication here, of course, is that the ranked list is not continuous (of course one could just treat it that way). I'm thinking I could create such a model in a PPL, but before I spend too much time on this, it would be good to know what has been done before.

Comment: [here is a list of some similar Qs](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fstats.stackexchange.com+average+of+rankings&oq=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fstats.stackexchange.com++++average+of+rankings&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.9270j0j4&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Something simple resembling what you're after would probably be Mallow's Model, which has an exponential parameter model the distances of the ranks observed from one consensus ranking, which is often estimated by some rank aggregation algorithm. There's a [nice introduction here](http://doi.org/10.18637/jss.v071.i12), and a [Bayesian R package implementation](http://doi.org/10.32614/RJ-2020-026). If instead you want to model the underlying "goodness" of each movie individually as giving rise to the ranks (with many more parameters), a Thurstonian or Plackett-Luce Model may work.

Comment: @awhug Thanks for the suggestion. I ended up using Plackett-Luce. You can check out the project. https://github.com/EvanZ/bayesian-meta-mock/blob/master/bayesian-meta-mock-draft.ipynb

Comment: @thecity2 Nice! One note: The connection to survival analysis may be closer than you think. You can actually fit a Plackett-Luce model as a Cox proportional hazards model, as it has an equivalent partial likelihood once you stratify by respondent (mock list in your case), per Allison & Christakis (1994). Felt inspired to [replicate your results here](https://gist.github.com/awhug/46d5d3dd0723fe4d4c8ec2a557830bad) albeit in a non-Bayesian manner - I used `survival` for R, but any survival analysis package that allows stratification will do.

Comment: @awhug Great! Thanks!